# Unique differentiable linear operator mapping $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I am trying to find a mapping $\phi$ such that:

1. $\phi$ uniquely maps $\mathbb{R}$ to the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^N$ (for bounded $N$), where every dimension of the vector is bounded between $-1$ and $1$.
2. $\phi$ is differentiable
3. $\phi$ forms a linear operator

Does such a mapping exist? My intuition tells me that the first criterion would require some sort of nonlinearity, which perhaps would make the last criterion infeasible.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "every dimension of the vector is bounded " ?

Comment: Given $x \in R^N$ every element within the vector $x$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$. For example $x = (-0.2, 0, 0.8)$ satisfies this criteria, but $x = (1.1, 0, 0.8)$ does not (because the first element is larger than $1$).

Comment: Are linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ bounded? I feel all such linear transformations are unbounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that if $\phi :\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^N$ is linear then $\phi$ is also differentiable so we need only investigate the first condition in detail.

The zero map $\phi :\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^N : v \mapsto \phi(v) = 0$ is the only linear map such that $ -1 \leq  \phi(v)_i \leq 1$ for all $v$.

If $\phi$ is not the zero map, then $\exists v : \phi(v) \neq 0.$ Using linearity  we have that $\phi(\lambda v) = \lambda \phi(v) \; \forall \lambda  \in \mathbb R.$ Therefore by taking $\lambda$ large enough we can find a vector whose components are not all between $-1$ and $1.$